# How can I replace duplicate text values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am looking for some help to replace duplicate text values that I have found in one of my columns. When I run the following code to give me a distinct list for the Data_File 'Sme' I get this result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Data_Source from master_table WHERE Data_File LIKE '%Sme%';
```

Output

```
Data_File
Sme
Sme
Sme
```

I then ran the following update query to replace them all:

```
UPDATE master_table SET Data_File = REPLACE(Data_File, 'Sme', 'SME') WHERE Data_File LIKE '%Sme%';
```

This matches all the rows and replaces them all but when I then run my original query I was expecting to only get 1 value but I get the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Data_Source from master_table WHERE Data_File LIKE '%SME%';
```

Output

```
Data_File
SME
SME
SME
```

Not sure where I am going wrong as I would have thought this would have given me 1 value and eliminated the duplicates.

Any advice would really be appreciated.

Comment: I think you may have other characters in this column, maybe invisible ones

Comment: Please post the CREATE & INSERT statements to create a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce the case you mentioned by appending white space characters in the column values. I am also able to see duplicates in that case only and otherwise not.

The issue is when you do replace query, you are just replacing one pattern by another pattern and all other characters remain as is it. If you could print length of the column values as well, you should find the difference there.

In the select query you could try to use trim() function after distinct clause. It should give you the expected result.

Comment: Hi Vishal, I printed the length as you mentioned and seen the difference in length for each one 3,4,5. Thank you so much